# Longest palindrome (dynamic programming) code fails with time-out for large inputs. How to improve it?

Tags: string, c++11, dynamic-programming, palindrome

I am learning to solve dynamic programming problems on LeetCode recently. The problem in hand is to find the longest palindrome in any given string. My code works well for small sized input strings. But fails for very large size inputs. Looking forward for ideas to improve it.

**Code :**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Solution {
    public:
    std::string longestPalindrome(std::string s) {
        std::vector<std::string> sequence;
        std::string dummy, longest;

        for(auto it = s.begin(); it < s.end(); it++){
            dummy += *it;
            for(auto  it2 = it+1; it2 < s.end(); it2++) {
                dummy += *it2;
                sequence.push_back(dummy);
            }
            dummy = "";
        }
        for(auto &item : sequence) {
            for(auto it = item.rbegin(); it < item.rend(); it++) {
                dummy += *it;
            }
            if(item == dummy && item.size() > longest.size()) {
                longest = item;
            }
            dummy = "";
        }
        if (longest.empty())
            longest += *s.begin();
        return longest;
    }
};

int main() {
Solution solver;
std::cout << solver.longestPalindrome("babadhabab") << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

Comment: your sequence vector contains string of order N^2 where N is the length of s and each string you push can be of size in order of N. hence your solution not working for large test cases. one hint is to think in term of indexes and think recursively

Answer (score 0):

I made some code and it works well, I think.
I'm not sure this code is perfect and fast.
but most of input data is not a palindrome, so this function will work well, I believe
(Algorithm) 
1. iterate every character and set char to pivot
2. check string whether it is a palindrome around pivot
3. most of input data is not a palindrome, so it 
4. WORST INPUT_DATA : all input data has same value like 'aaaaaaaaaa'

```
    class Solution {
        public:
        std::string longestPalindrome(std::string const& input)
        {
            if (2 > input.length()) { return std::string(); }

            char const* input_data = input.c_str();
            int found_palindrome_max_len = 0;
            char const* found_palindrome = nullptr;
            char const* current = input_data+1;
            while ('\0' != *current)
            {
                auto palindrome = is_palindrome(input_data, current, found_palindrome_max_len);
                if (nullptr != palindrome) { found_palindrome = palindrome; }
                ++current;
            }

            if (nullptr == found_palindrome) { return std::string(); }
            return input.substr(found_palindrome - input_data, found_palindrome_max_len);
        }

        char const* is_palindrome(char const* begin, char const* pivot, int& max_palindrome_len)
        {
            std::cout << "[BEGIN] pivot=" << *pivot << ", max_len = " << max_palindrome_len << std::endl;
            bool is_odd_check = true; // ex) abcba (odd length)
            bool is_even_check = true; // ex) abccba (even lenth)
            int length = 1;
            char const* left = nullptr;
            char const* right = nullptr;
            char const* found = nullptr;
            while (true == is_odd_check || true == is_even_check)
            {
                if (true == is_even_check && 0 == length % 2)   // even length check
                {
                    left = pivot - length/2 + 1;
                    right = pivot + length/2;
                    std::cout <<  "(even)length=" << length << ", pivot=" << *pivot <<", left=" << *left << ", right=" << *right << std::endl;
                    if (*left != *right)
                    {
                        std::cout << "is_even_check = false" << std::endl;
                        is_even_check = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (length > max_palindrome_len)
                        { 
                            found = left; max_palindrome_len = length;
                            std::cout << "max_palindrome_len = " << length << ", found=" << left << std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (true == is_odd_check && 1 == length % 2)// odd length check
                {
                    left = pivot - length/2;
                    right = pivot + length/2;
                    std::cout <<  "(odd)length=" << length << ", pivot=" << *pivot <<", left=" << *left << ", right=" << *right << std::endl;
                    if (*left != *right)
                    {
                        std::cout << "is_odd_check = false" << std::endl;
                        is_odd_check = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (length > max_palindrome_len)
                        { 
                            found = left; max_palindrome_len = length;
                            std::cout << "max_palindrome_len = " << length << ", found=" << left << std::endl;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (begin == left || '\0' == right+1)
                {
                    break;
                }
                ++length;
            }

            return found;
        }
    };

    void TestPalin()
    {
        Solution solver;
        auto found = solver.longestPalindrome("123abba");
        std::cout << "PALINDROME = " << found << std::endl;
    }
```